# Asynchronous image loading in iPhone?

Tags: url, asynchronous, uiimage, nsmutablearray

Hi i'm new to iPhone application.In my application i used tableview.

when i click table cell it does to detail view which has UIScrollview. where i'm loading

images from the NSMutableArray. and in that NSMutableArray there are some URL images.

when i click table cell it takes more time to load all images.

please i need help to complete my application.Many people said to do asynchronously

but i don't know how to do.

thanks in advance. waiting for a solution .

Comment: http://blog.grio.com/2013/04/loading-an-image-asynchronously-in-ios.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a library such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) to load your images, it handles downloading and swapping in the image on the tableView.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would like recommend you [Paul Hegarty tutorials](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) (in Lectures 9, 10 and mainly 11 (multithreading)) you can learn too much.

Here some sample code can help you quickly but superfluously:

```
dispatch_queue_t imageFetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("image fetcher", NULL);
    dispatch_async(imageFetchQ, ^{
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.imageURL];  // could take a while
        // UIImage is one of the few UIKit objects which is thread-safe, so we can do this here
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        // check to make sure we are even still interested in this image (might have touched away)
        if (self.imageURL == imageURL) {
            // dispatch back to main queue to do UIKit work
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (image) {
                    self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
                    self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
                    self.imageView.image = image;
                    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```